# Tengo muchas carpetas a la hora de compilar react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy subiendo mi proyecto de react a produccion, al host mi aplicacion todo funciona muy buen, pero a la hora de inspeccionar la pagina he irme a source, veo demaciadas carpetas que no que no estaban a la hora de compilar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me pongo a revisar otros proyectos y aparece asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un proyecto reac, y esta mucho mas minimizado que el mio,
Si alguien sabe como minimizar mi carpeta para que luzca de esa manera, se lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas usando tu proyecto en modo de desarrollo. Pará poder tener una aplicación para producción tienes que ejecutar el comando adecuado para obtener tus archivos estáticos los cuales te servirán para subir tu página a tu hosting.

Si revisas tu *package.json* tendrás un fragmento muy parecido a esto:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

Ejecuta `npm run build` para poder generar los archivos mencionados dentro de la carpeta `/build`